# functions in PHP class didn't work

Tags: php

I build a PHP class.

Why when I build functions (in PHP class) like this, it didn't work?

And how could I fix this?

**the functions:** *(I delete the `__construct` because its isn't interesting right now)*

```
class c  {
    public function a() {
        return b();     // line 131
    }
    public function b() {
        return 1;
    }
}

$x = new c;
$x->a();
```

**this is the error that I see:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function b() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\tb\index.php on line 131
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling a method within the class you need to prefix with *this* (or `self` if it's a static method).

```
public function a() {
    echo $this->b();
}
```

I encourage you to read the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) for an introduction to classes and objects in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like

```
  public function a() {
        echo c::b();  // c is your class name.
    }
```

Comment: Why reference an instance method statically?

Comment: Can you list the drawback of this ? Thanks.

Comment: Although it works, it's technically incorrect. It would be evident if `b()` attempted to access `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call b(), inside a(), you may try this:

`public function a() { return self::b(); }`

Comment: Why reference an instance method statically?